# Convert member function pointer to function pointer in FreePascal

Tags: function-pointers, freepascal, pointer-to-member

I want to pass to a GLUT function (`glutKeyboardFunc`) a pointer to a member function (`TDisplayer.GlKeyboard`). GLUT callback just accept function pointer. Is there a way to "pack" self pointer into the function ?

```
unit UDisplayer;

{$mode objfpc}

interface

type
   TDisplayer = class(TObject)

public
   constructor Create(x, y : Integer; caption : AnsiString);
   destructor Destroy; override;

   procedure GlKeyboard(key : Byte; x, y : Longint); cdecl; 

private
   winX : Integer;
   winY : Integer;
end;

implementation

uses gl, glut, glext, UTools;

constructor TDisplayer.Create(x, y : Integer; caption : AnsiString);
var
   cmd          : array of PChar;
   cmdCount     : Integer;
   keyboardCallback : pointer;
begin
   winX := x;
   winY := y;
   cmdCount := 1;
   SetLength(cmd, cmdCount);
   cmd[0] := PChar(ParamStr(0));
   glutInit(@cmdCount, @cmd);
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE or GLUT_RGB or GLUT_DEPTH);
   glutInitWindowSize(x, y);
   glutCreateWindow(PChar(caption));

   glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0);

   //glutKeyBoardFunc(@self.glKeyBoard); <--- HERE

   glutMainLoop;
end;

destructor TDisplayer.Destroy;
begin
   inherited;
end;

procedure TDisplayer.GlKeyboard(key : Byte; x, y : Longint); cdecl;
begin
end;

end.
```

Comment: Your code please. Which GLUT function? What's the "member function"?

Comment: I talk about the keyboard callback for exemple (GlKeyboard()). My code : http://pastie.org/9998941

Comment: **1)** If the number of callbacks is known at compile-time then you can create simple functions passed to OpenGL which would then redirect the call to a class instance stored in a global variable **2)** If the number of callbacks will not be known until run-time then you can use code similar to the `MakeObjectInstance` trick which generates small wrapping machine code dynamically, see http://svn.freepascal.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/rtl/win32/classes.pp?view=markup for the details **3)** Maybe there are some object-oriented OpenGL wrappers dealing with this problem already available

Answer (score 0):

No. A method pointer is two pointers large,  and a simple function pointer only one, so it simply won't fit.

If the callback system provides some "context" you can sometimes pass the instance into the context, and make a somewhat more  general thunk like

```
function callme(context:pointer;x,y:integer);integer; cdecl;
begin
  TTheClass(context).callme(x,y);
end;
```

Then pass "Self" as context when registering the callback. But it doesn't look like this callback setter has a context that is passed back to the callback when it is called.

Answer (score 0):

In a first time, declare the callback as a global procedure.
It'll be a context-independent method, not relying on **Self**

```
 type TDisplayer = class(TObject)
 public
   constructor Create(x, y : Integer; caption : AnsiString);
   destructor Destroy; override;
 private
   winX : Integer;
   winY : Integer;
 end;  

 procedure GlKeyboard(key : Byte; x, y : Longint); cdecl;
```

Then since **glutCreateWindow()** returns an unique context, you can use it to associate it to your class instance. So you define an associative array wich allows to retrieve a **TDisplayer** instance using a GLUT window as Key:

```
type TCtxtArr = specialize TFPGMap<Integer,TForm>;
```

You add one as a global var which will be created and freed in the **initialization** and the **finalization** sections:

```
var
  ctxtarray: TCtxtArr; 
initialization
  ctxtarray:= TCtxtArr.create;
finalization
  ctxtarray.free;
end.
```

Then in **TDisplayer.Create()** you add an entry to the AA:

```
// id is a local integer.
id = glutCreateWindow(PChar(caption));
ctxtarray.Add(id, Self);
// assign the callback here or elsewhere
glutKeyBoardFunc(@glKeyBoard);
```

When your callback is called, you can retrieve the **TDisplayer** instance, so that you can access to its variables and methods:

```
procedure GlKeyboard(key : Byte; x, y : Longint); cdecl;
var
  disp: TDisplayer;
  id: integer;
begin
  glutGetWindow(id);
  disp := ctxtarray[id];
end;
```

Unfortunately, i cant test the answer as it seems to be part of a bigger program. However this sample works in an analog way:

```
unit Unit1;
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
interface
uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, dialogs, fgl;

type
  TForm1 = class;
  TProc = procedure(x,y: integer);
  TCtxtArr = specialize TFPGMap<Integer,TForm1>;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    constructor Create(TheOwner: TComponent); override;
    procedure hello;
  end;

  procedure callback(x,y: integer);

var
  Form1: TForm1; Proc: TProc;
  ctxtarray: TCtxtArr;

implementation
{$R *.lfm}

constructor TForm1.Create(TheOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  proc := @callback;
  ctxtarray.Add(0,Self);
  proc(0,0);
end;

procedure TForm1.hello;
begin
  showmessage('hello');
end;

procedure callback(x, y: integer);
var
  frm: TForm1;
begin
  frm := ctxtarray.Data[0];
  frm.hello;
end;

initialization
  ctxtarray:= TCtxtArr.create;
finalization
  ctxtarray.free;
end.
```

As a foot note: theorically FPC allows to define **static** class methods (similar to global procedures), but for some reason it seems that they cant be assigned to a global procedure pointer, at least it fails with FPC 2.6.4

Answer (score 0):

You have to assemble some bytecode and keep wrapper with 'hardcoded' self pointer, which manages invocation stack:

```
procOfObj = packed record
    method : pointer;
    this   : pointer; 
    end;

obj = packed object
    procedure ASIOBufferSwitch(
      ip: pointer; {the added IP artifact }
      doubleBufferIndex: longint; directProcess: longbool); cdecl;
    end;

cdeclProxy = packed object
    procedure  build( const src: procOfObj );    
    private
    push         : byte; push_arg: pointer;
    call         : byte; call_arg: pointer;
    add_ret      : longint;
    end;

procedure cdeclProxy.build( const src: procOfObj );
begin
    push := $68; push_arg := src.this;
    call := $e8; call_arg := pointer( src.method - @call - 5 );
    add_ret := $c304c483;
    result := @push;
end;

var cdp : cdeclProxy;
    o   : obj;
begin
    cdp.build( procOfObj( @o.ASIOBufferSwitch ))
    pointer(... procedure var ...) := @cdp;
end.
```

Notice that provided example requires additional arg in method signature, but it allows to build wrapper without knowledge of arg count. If you do not want ip arg, you have to re-push all args again before calling actual method and then clean up stack inside wrapper.